# "XXX", referenced from: XXX constin libXXX.a (XXX.o) problem using C++ and C mixed with Objective C++ for Iphone library/game

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, cross-platform, static-libraries

I'm developing an static library for PC/Iphone.

Library is called libNerv.lib / libNERV.a

The Project is written in C++ (+Objective C++ for iphone)

Until now everything worked fine for pc and iphone.
The game app uses the library and links it fine. but now I have to use libpng for the project.
I want to share one library so I included the .c file from libpng into my library project. On windows everything works fine! The game can link against my library without problems.

Today I moved on to Iphone added the libpng files to the iphone project and the library builds fine. Soon as I build the game app the linker fails with following messages:

```
  "_png_read_image", referenced from:


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


  "_png_create_read_struct", referenced from:


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


  "_png_read_end", referenced from:


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


  "_png_destroy_read_struct", referenced from:


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


  "_png_read_info", referenced from:


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


  "_png_read_update_info", referenced from:


      NERV::Video::LoadPNG::loadImage(NERV::IO::IFileReader*) constin libNERV.a(LoadPNG.o)


ld: symbol(s) not found


collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is a problem because it simply ignors all my tries. (NOTE, it woks with VS 2008 on pc!!)
I have tried several things to get rid of the linker errors:

I have tried to change all libpng files from .c to cpp which worked quite well, I had just to resolve 2 typecast errors (void* to char*), but I had still the same errors.
I have tried to create a own library for he libpng files. But it didn't work either.

I tried to open my libNerv.a with ar, libtool, ranlib without any success (just told me it is created with fat... or something)

libpng files use extern C declarations for cpp projects so I don't know if it is good to compile it with cpp. Maybe someone knows more on that too.

There is on thing I haven't tried yet. I will add the libpng files to the game app and compile it with the app but I don't think this will work.

(Note: all reference problems are in the same method, and I don't use libpng anywhere else - this method is in libNerv.a which builds without problems. The problems only occur one the libNerv.a gets linked with the iphone app!)

I hope someone can help me with this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the resulting `libpng.a` (or something like that) as one of the libraries linked to the **main executable**?

You successfully built `libNERV.a` which means you added `libpng.a` in the list of libraries used to make `libNERV.a`.

But you need to specify `libpng.a` in the linker setting for the main executable, too.

Comment: Basically libpng is not a library which would be a single lib, neither do I link libpng.a to libnerv.a. I included .c and .h files from libpng to my libnerv.a project and just compile alltogether into libnerv.a

e.g.:

FILES (library): core files, service files, png files, zlib files
OUTPUT: libnerv.a (linked with standard libs)

FILES (app): game files 
OUTPUT: game.app (linked with libnerv.a and standard libs)


But I have tried to compile a single library only including png stuff so I link nerv.a and png.a with my app (but there was the same project)

Comment: Mmm ... that should work, then. Could you post the command line which makes libnerv.a and your main executable? It's buried in the Build window of XCode.

Comment: I don't know why because I changed simply nothing :/ but it works right now ... However maybe it will occur again, where would I find the command line exactly, because I'm not sure what you mean and I always seached something comparable to the VS output window :)

Comment: That's explained here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/210-Building_Products/building.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002693-SW18 See Fig. 8.8.